# R Shiny: Nested tabPanels disable each other

Tags: r, shiny

In the attached MWE Shiny example, I have a nested tabsetPanel within a tabPanel for a navbar. If you run the MWE with only one tabPanel within the tabSet you will see that Shiny behaves exactly as it is expected. However, if you run the MWE with two tabPanels, the result is not printed to the main panel of each tab.

Why does this behaviour occur? And how do I resolve this conundrum?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("tabalicious", 
                     tabPanel("Nav1", value = "nav1", 
                              mainPanel(h2("Hello"),
                                        br(),
                                        p("This is my app.")
                              )
                     )
                     ,
                     tabPanel("Nav2", value = "nav2", 
                              tabsetPanel(
                                tabPanel("tabsettab1",
                                         sidebarLayout(
                                           sidebarPanel(
                                             helpText("Choose your settings"),
                                             selectInput("zone_type",
                                                         label = "Choose a zone type to display",
                                                         choices = list("Industrial", "Residential"),
                                                         selected = "Industrial")
                                           ),
                                           mainPanel(h2("A tab for a tabSet"),
                                                     textOutput('zone_type')
                                           )
                                         )
                                )
                                # Uncomment this to see the issue
                                # ,
                                # tabPanel("tabsettab2",
                                #          sidebarLayout(
                                #            sidebarPanel(
                                #              helpText("Choose your settings"),
                                #              selectInput("zone_type",
                                #                          label = "Choose a zone type to display",
                                #                          choices = list("Industrial", "Residential"),
                                #                          selected = "Industrial")
                                #            ),
                                #            mainPanel(h2("A tab for a tabSet"),
                                #                      textOutput('zone_type')
                                #            )
                                #          )
                                # )
                                  )
                         )
)
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$zone_type <- renderText({ 
    paste("You have selected", input$zone_type)
  })
})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It's not about the tabs, it's about two `textOutput` calls to render the same `zone_type` variable, which `shinyUI` can't handle. You can duplicate `output$zone_type` under another name in your server function, if you need.

Comment: Add as an answer alistaire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have to do with tabs, but multiple calls to output the results of the same `render*` function. For example, a simplified page (with no tabs) will work fine, but if you uncomment the duplicated call, will fail to display `zone_type`:

```
library(shiny)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$zone_type <- renderText({paste("You have selected", input$zone_type)})
})

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  selectInput("zone_type",
              label = "Choose a zone type to display",
              choices = list("Industrial", "Residential")),
  # textOutput('zone_type'),
  textOutput('zone_type')
))

runApp(shinyApp(server = server, ui = ui))
```

While your `shinyUI` function can only call each output of `shinyServer` once, within `shinyServer` you can call the inputs as many times as you like, so it's easy to duplicate outputs:

```
library(shiny)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$zone_type <- renderText({paste("You have selected", input$zone_type)})
  output$zone_type2 <- renderText({paste("You have selected", input$zone_type)})
})

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  selectInput("zone_type",
              label = "Choose a zone type to display",
              choices = list("Industrial", "Residential")),
  textOutput('zone_type'),
  textOutput('zone_type2')
))

runApp(shinyApp(server = server, ui = ui))
```

If you don't want to duplicate work for the server, you can't pass one output to another, but you can just save the `render*` results to a local variable which you can pass to both outputs:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  zone <- renderText({paste("You have selected", input$zone_type)})
  output$zone_type <- zone
  output$zone_type2 <- zone
})
```